# Get only visible x axis dates when zooming in highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, highcharts

I have a reasonably complicated chart created using highcharts and ajax, it contains stacked columns and multiple spline graphs using the datetime xAxis.

I am also generating a HTML table of data from the chart data that regenerates based on user selection events such as turning series on/off using the legend. This works fine but what i am having trouble with is collecting the correct data when a user zooms in (it still grabs all the data from first date to end date).

The main issue is the fact that i cannot seem to find a variable such as visible : true in order to differentiate whether the xAxis value is present in the current view during a loop. I have looked through the chart object including series, points and so on with no luck.

I have also tried using getExtremes but the values appear to be off from the actual dates by some thousands of milliseconds (i will look into this method again tomorrow)

Below is a small snippet of code that is used before i build the HTML table in jQuery to gather some of the data.

```
  $.each(chart.series, function (i, item) {
        //Generation Data
        if (item.name === "Generation") {
            generation.push(item.yData);
        }
        //Check if points are defined and then loop to get total circuit data
        if (typeof (item.points) !== "undefined") {
            $.each(item.points, function (j, point) {
                //Check if asset is visible
                if (point.series.visible === true) {
                    var type = point.series.options.type;
                    //Get only data that is a column (asset)
                    if (type !== "spline" || typeof (type) === "undefined") {
                        //Check if previous key exists already or not
                        if (typeof (totalCircuits[point.x]) === 'undefined') {
                            totalCircuits[point.x] = point.y;
                        }
                        else {
                            var oldVal = 0;
                            oldVal = totalCircuits[point.x];
                            var newVal = oldVal + point.y;
                            totalCircuits[point.x] = newVal;
                        }
                    }
                }

            });
        }
    });
```

Hope that makes at least some sense and any Help or direction would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you make a small fiddle that we can look at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the axis.getExtremes() function on the x axis, you should be able to check your x values as you loop to see if they are within the min/max x axis values, and thereby determine whether or not they are visible at the current zoom level.

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.getExtremes

Comment: Thanks @jlbriggs, its so simple when you look at it this way, i didnt even think to compare the values. Thanks for saving me hours of unnecessary over complication :)